# Write Is Not Defined in Python 3.7.4

Tags: python, python-3.7, turtle-graphics

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zoome\Desktop\NVIDIA\source\GPU NVIDIA 1060.py", line 17, in <module>
    write("values", font=('Arial', 12, 'normal'))
NameError: name 'write' is not defined
```

when i atempt to use turtle text. i think its just spelling error can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you expect `write` to be defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way a bare `write()` should work is if you imported turtle via:

```
from turtle import *
```

If you instead did:

```
import turtle
```

then we'd expect to say:

```
turtle.write("values", font=('Arial', 12, 'normal'))
```

Or, if you created your own turtle instance, then it could differ yet again:

```
import turtle
yertle = turtle.Turtle()
yertle.write("values", font=('Arial', 12, 'normal'))
```

This is why it's important that you include your code that failed, along with the error messages, when you ask for help.